# Git: How can I prevent a specific commit from being merged into another branch?

Tags: git, merge

Our company Git workflow is as following: we have a `master` branch, some `feature/*` branches to develop new features that are merged back to `master` when the job is done, and also `release/*` branches. These branches are created before a product release and are designed for bug fixes, with no new feature, and those bug fixes are then merged back occasionally into the `master` branch.

From time to time, it happens that a specific commit in a `release/*` branch is a change that we **don't** want to merge back to `master`: for example when the release number is incremented. Since there are other important fixes in the branch, for sure someone *will* sooner or later incorporate that said *local* commit into `master`, breaking something in the main branch.

The current "solution" I know about is to merge the `release/*` branch into `master` immediately after the local commit is done, *revert* the local commit and then push. It kind of works, but the history is not clean. In addition, this does not prevent the local commit to be merged into another branch than `master`.

Is there any better way to solve that problem in the described workflow ?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, it is not possible to merge in a commit without also merging in all of its parent commits, which sounds like what you are trying to do.

However, a slight change to your workflow could fix this issue.

Similar to the [Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) model, you can create a `hotfix/*` branch to fix the bug, instead of committing directly to the `release` branch. This branch should probably be based off of `master` (at the first commit that is a parent of any relevant `release` branches), and it should be merged into `master` as well as any `release` branches it affects.

That way, the `release` branches need never be merged into `master`, and can be reserved for release-specific fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not isolating the bug-fixes on the `release/*` branch as individual commits (i.e. without the release version updates) and then cherry-picking these commits to `master`, as pretty well described [here](https://ariejan.net/2010/06/10/cherry-picking-specific-commits-from-another-branch/)?